# Spring Framework & RestTemplate: not being able to consume REST Service

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

First of all, I have two Spring REST Services: **Service A** and **Service B**. **Service A** will need to consume some methods exposed by **Service B**. Both, **A** and **B**, are Spring `@RestController`.

**Service A** has a *POST* method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mediumcandy/linkreachable", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<ShortURL> shortenerIfReachable(@RequestParam("url") String url,
            @RequestParam(value = "sponsor", required = false) String sponsor,
            @RequestParam(value = "brand", required = false) String brand,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        ShortURL su = null;

        /*************************************************************
         * CONSUMING REST Service
         *************************************************************/
        Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
        vars.put("url", url);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        su = restTemplate.postForObject("http://SERVICE_URI_HERE/linkreachable", null, ShortURL.class, vars);
        /****************************************************************/

        if (su != null) {
            HttpHeaders h = new HttpHeaders();
            h.setLocation(su.getUri());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(su, h, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

And the *POST* method in **Service B** called by **Service A** using Spring RestTemplate is the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/linkreachable", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ShortURL shortenerIfReachable(@RequestParam("url") String url,
        @RequestParam(value = "sponsor", required = false) String sponsor,
        @RequestParam(value = "brand", required = false) String brand,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    ShortURL su = null;
    boolean isReachableUrl = ping(url);

    if (isReachableUrl){
        su = createAndSaveIfValid(url, sponsor, brand, UUID
                .randomUUID().toString(), extractIP(request));
        System.out.println("URL REACHABLE!");
    }

    return su;
}
```

The RestTemplate method `postForObject()` in **Service A** is giving me trouble, always throwing `HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request`:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw
exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.H
ttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultR
esponseErrorHandler.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.ja
va:615)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:573)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:537)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:339
)
        at urlshortener2014.mediumcandy.web.MediumCandyController.shortenerIfReachable(Med
iumCandyController.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja
va:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(Invocabl
eHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(
InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMe
thod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdap
ter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdap
ter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(
AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:94
... etc
```

I've followed some Spring Tutorials to build my Service, and also have checked the Spring Framework api-docs but I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Can you please post the web.xml and please confirm that when you test Service B individually (not by calling service A) it works as expected?

Comment: @liorsolomon yes, Service B individually works fine. I'm not using a web.xml as I'm not deploying to an external instance.
I did it the way it is explained here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: @liorsolomon here's the project's repo:
https://github.com/charliemc/UrlShortener2014/tree/developer/mediumCandy/src/main/java/urlshortener2014/mediumcandy
`MediumCandyController` is **Service A** and `UrlShortenerControllerWithLogs` is **Service B**

Comment: it works for me. I couldn't reproduce the problem. can you please explain how are you testing the service?

Comment: @liorsolomon Is it? I am using 'curl' this way:
`curl -v -d "url=http://www.stackoverflow.com/" -X POST http://localhost:8080/mediumcandy/linkreachable
` and it keeps answering with **Bad Request** (Server also prints out a Exception)

Comment: @liorsolomon I have just tried also testing it with SoapUI (`http://localhost:8080/mediumcandy/linkreachable?url=http://www.stackoverflow.com`) and I keep getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spring HATEOAS to solve it! Given `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, in `ServiceA` use Spring HATEOAS for obtaining the runtime URL of the controller/method in 'ServiceB` as follows:

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn;
...
String restURI = linkTo(methodOn(ServiceB.class).
  shortenerIfReachable(null, null, null, null)).toString();
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
su = restTemplate.postForObject(restURI, null, ShortURL.class, vars);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with `methodOn()`: Compiler says it is *undefined fot the type **Class<ServiceB>***

Comment: As I was telling @liorsolomon I was totally believing that Eclipse IDE was doing those imports automatically. Checked that, and now it compiles fine!

Comment: Then mark this answer as the solution to your help request XD

Answer (score 2):

@Francisco you were almost there

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn;
...
String restURI = linkTo(methodOn(UrlShortenerControllerWithLogs.class).
                shortenerIfReachable(url, null, null, null)).toString();

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

su = restTemplate.postForObject(restURI, null, ShortURL.class);
```

You have to pass the url parameter when calling shortenerIfReachable 
and I also removed the vars from the postForObject call.

Comment: I'm still having issues with this method: `methodOn()`
Compiler keeps saying it is *undefined fot the type Class<ServiceB>*

Comment: Oh sorry! I was totally believing that Eclipse IDE was doing those imports automatically. Checked that, and now **works fine**!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following url : `curl --data "url=http://www.stackoverflow.com" http://localhost:8080/linkreachable`

Comment: That way works fine, but that way also is not using **Service A**. I need to call that `/linkreachable` method in **Service B** from **Service A**'s method `/mediumcandy/linkreachable` (I know it might sound a bit stupid because the result is just the same, but I have to do it this way).

Comment: just imagine **Service A** is a Java client that is consuming a REST API (**Service B**), that's what I need.